# XPATH Найти элемент одной ветки дерева по элементу соседней ветки

Tags: xpath

```html
<div class="file">
  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}-->
  <div _ngcontent-c46="" appvirtualscroll="" class="file ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-klass="file" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
    <!---->
    <div _ngcontent-c46="" class="file__checkbox">
      <div _ngcontent-c46="" class="form__fieldset"><label _ngcontent-c46="" class="label"><input _ngcontent-c46="" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"><span _ngcontent-c46="" class="checkbox-custom"></span></label></div>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-c46="" class="file__main">
      <div _ngcontent-c46="" class="file__details"><button _ngcontent-c46="" class="doc-link"><div _ngcontent-c46="" class="file-list__text"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "лк_док.pdf"
}--><p _ngcontent-c46="" class="file-list__text-doc-name ng-star-inserted" title="лк_док.pdf">лк_док</p><!--bindings={}--></div></button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div _ngcontent-c46="" appvirtualscroll="" class="file ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-klass="file" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
    <!---->
    <div _ngcontent-c46="" class="file__checkbox">
      <div _ngcontent-c46="" class="form__fieldset"><label _ngcontent-c46="" class="label"><input _ngcontent-c46="" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"><span _ngcontent-c46="" class="checkbox-custom"></span></label></div>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-c46="" class="file__main">
      <div _ngcontent-c46="" class="file__details"><button _ngcontent-c46="" class="doc-link"><div _ngcontent-c46="" class="file-list__text"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "тест_doc.doc"
}--><p _ngcontent-c46="" class="file-list__text-doc-name ng-star-inserted" title="тест_doc.doc">тест_doc</p><!--bindings={}--></div></button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div _ngcontent-c46="" appvirtualscroll="" class="file ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-klass="file" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
    <!---->
    <div _ngcontent-c46="" class="file__checkbox">
      <div _ngcontent-c46="" class="form__fieldset"><label _ngcontent-c46="" class="label"><input _ngcontent-c46="" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"><span _ngcontent-c46="" class="checkbox-custom"></span></label></div>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-c46="" class="file__main">
      <div _ngcontent-c46="" class="file__details"><button _ngcontent-c46="" class="doc-link"><div _ngcontent-c46="" class="file-list__text"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "тест_rtf.rtf"
}--><p _ngcontent-c46="" class="file-list__text-doc-name ng-star-inserted" title="тест_rtf.rtf">тест_rtf</p><!--bindings={}--></div></button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Надо найти чек поле нужного документа.

чекбокс по имени документа в атрибуте title элемента

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вложенный xpath:

```
//div[.//p[contains(@title,'лк_док.pdf')] and contains(@class,'file')]//div[contains(@class,'file__checkbox')]//label
```

Comment: Данное выражение избыточно вернёт все три чекбокса. Для того, чтобы получить только чекбокс, соответствующий названию файла, необходимо добавить проверку атрибутов тега, который имеет лишь только тот чекбокс, что действительно относится к разыскиваемой ноде:
```$x("//div[@_ngcontent-c46][.//p[contains(@title,'лк_док.pdf')] and contains(@class,'file')]//div[contains(@class,'file__checkbox')]//label")```